Migrating threads to Cross Validated
Should there be an option for migrating threads to Cross Validated under Flag --> Should be closed --> Off topic because... --> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network?
I see quite a few questions that stand as pure statistical questions and do not need expertise in finance to be answered.

Adding this option is not possible for the regular moderators but the Community Managers can do it. So I'm hoping @ana can look into this.

Let me add: I'm not advocating adding the option but I see that it could make sense. However, we as a community can't implement doing this so let's figure out whether this is an option at all.

@BobJansen, thank you. I think the amount of purely statistical questions here is significant, but I don't have that good of an overview in general. Probably there are other sites to which even more questions could be migrated but which I am not aware of.

@shog9 does this make sense for us?

Unfortunately, suggesting migrations to other sites is only possible if a migration path exists between the two sites. Migration paths only exist for sites that have graduated (i.e. are out of Beta) and as of now we're still in Beta.
Fortunately, our beta period won't be forever ^_^. 

Got it. Thank you.

Update? Is the site out of beta?

Yes, we are although it's barely visible.

We have a framework for evaluating when a migration path is worthy of creation, which you can find here.
Looking at your stats, you've only had 2 questions migrated to CV over the past 90 days... one of which was rejected. As it stands, I don't think a migration path is needed. 
Obviously, this can change in the future — if you see a question that belongs on CV, flag it for moderation attention, to ask for migration. If this happens more often than it does now, and a moderator asks us to look again, it can be enough to enable a migration path then.

Thank you for the update. I visited QF Stack Exchange just a few times over the last 90 days, so I am not up to date on the question content situation, but consider this: I alone have flagged 11 threads over a period of less than 6 months (hence, about 2 a month) in 2016 when I was active on QF Stack Exchange. I suppose this is a substantial amount in the perspective of all questions that were moved over that period (I do not have the statistics on all moves, though). Moreover, I wonder why Cross Validated should not be one of the most natural paths due to the very nature of QF Stack Exchange.

While your numbers do show steadiness, they also relate to over 2 years ago — they didn't keep that consistency 'til today, hence my rejection of the migration path creation, for the time being :)

I understand. Just for the reference, my request was is equally old (posted 2 years ago – when I was an active contributor), but I know fulfilling it was not possible back then. Thanks anyway.

Oh, I know your request is old — a mod asked us to reevaluate! :)
